# AEM / CQ5 CMS Application Very Slow (what happened? sar %user load average, etc.)

Tags: java, performance, aem, sar

We're running Adobe AEM 5.6.1 Author (w/ Oracle JDK 1.7.0.79) and it became very slow to login and use today (reported around 3:50PM - though the numbers in sar indicate it may have started at 1:30PM). Restarting the app around 4:00PM seems to have fixed. sar reports high %user numbers during the slow performance, and low idle numbers (which indicate high CPU use?), but the load average history doesn't show high CPU load? Wondering if these stats shed any light onto the app performance? Does %user indicate user (Application) process stats? Our CMS runs with a dedicated user, wondering if %user corresponds to it possibly?

Thanks for any help in interpreting these statistics.

```
sar 

12:30:01 PM     all      2.93      0.00      0.11      0.04      0.00     96.92
12:35:01 PM     all      0.84      0.00      0.10      0.05      0.00     99.01
12:40:01 PM     all      0.71      0.00      0.10      0.19      0.00     99.01
12:45:01 PM     all     15.90      0.00      0.26      1.33      0.00     82.52
12:50:02 PM     all     34.07      0.00      0.61      0.98      0.00     64.34
12:55:01 PM     all      4.38      0.00      0.20      1.13      0.00     94.29
01:00:01 PM     all      1.43      0.00      0.09      0.19      0.00     98.29
01:05:01 PM     all      0.68      0.00      0.09      0.08      0.00     99.16
01:10:01 PM     all      0.72      0.00      0.09      0.01      0.00     99.18
01:15:01 PM     all      0.52      0.00      0.08      0.05      0.00     99.35
01:20:01 PM     all      9.05      0.00      0.28      0.07      0.00     90.59
01:25:01 PM     all      2.27      0.00      0.09      0.03      0.00     97.61
01:30:01 PM     all      9.09      0.00      0.16      0.56      0.00     90.19
01:35:01 PM     all     62.01      0.00      1.03      0.04      0.00     36.91
01:40:01 PM     all     64.15      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00     34.84
01:45:01 PM     all     61.54      0.00      1.03      0.06      0.00     37.36
01:50:01 PM     all     60.88      0.00      1.20      0.01      0.00     37.91
01:55:01 PM     all     61.26      0.00      1.01      0.01      0.00     37.72
02:00:01 PM     all     61.14      0.00      1.04      0.18      0.00     37.63
02:05:01 PM     all     55.88      0.00      0.87      0.11      0.00     43.14
02:10:01 PM     all     54.84      0.00      0.97      0.31      0.00     43.88
02:15:01 PM     all     60.95      0.00      1.01      0.07      0.00     37.97
02:20:01 PM     all     61.66      0.00      1.26      0.08      0.00     37.00

02:20:01 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
02:25:01 PM     all     61.53      0.00      1.04      0.15      0.00     37.28
02:30:01 PM     all     61.61      0.00      1.40      0.78      0.00     36.21
2:35:01 PM     all     61.05      0.00      1.02      0.18      0.00     37.76
02:40:01 PM     all     61.19      0.00      0.97      0.01      0.00     37.83
02:45:01 PM     all     60.64      0.00      1.03      0.04      0.00     38.29
02:50:01 PM     all     61.95      0.00      1.37      0.09      0.00     36.60
02:55:01 PM     all     59.88      0.00      1.04      0.05      0.00     39.03
03:00:01 PM     all     60.65      0.00      1.07      0.14      0.00     38.14
03:05:01 PM     all     61.27      0.00      1.09      0.46      0.00     37.17
03:10:01 PM     all     61.75      0.00      1.15      0.09      0.00     37.01
03:15:01 PM     all     60.93      0.00      1.05      0.03      0.00     37.98
03:20:01 PM     all     61.53      0.00      1.43      0.13      0.00     36.91
03:25:01 PM     all     61.28      0.00      1.02      0.03      0.00     37.68
03:30:02 PM     all     58.65      0.00      0.98      0.70      0.00     39.66
03:35:01 PM     all     41.16      0.00      0.60      0.04      0.00     58.20
03:40:01 PM     all     16.15      0.00      0.26      0.01      0.00     83.58
03:45:01 PM     all     27.60      0.00      0.54      1.03      0.00     70.83
03:50:01 PM     all     65.87      0.00      1.38      0.27      0.00     32.48
03:55:01 PM     all     51.00      0.00      0.87      0.05      0.00     48.08
04:00:01 PM     all     10.88      0.00      0.40      2.55      0.00     86.16
04:05:01 PM     all      7.13      0.00      1.42      2.09      0.00     89.36
04:10:01 PM     all      3.31      0.00      0.41      2.72      0.00     93.56
04:15:01 PM     all      3.80      0.00      0.22      2.00      0.00     93.98
04:20:01 PM     all      3.68      0.00      0.35      1.07      0.00     94.89
04:25:01 PM     all      3.93      0.00      0.33      0.62      0.00     95.13
04:30:01 PM     all      1.57      0.00      0.11      0.56      0.00     97.77
04:35:01 PM     all      0.24      0.00      0.06      0.01      0.00     99.69
04:40:01 PM     all      1.47      0.00      0.17      0.05      0.00     98.31
04:45:01 PM     all      1.31      0.00      0.09      0.33      0.00     98.27
04:50:01 PM     all      2.99      0.00      0.37      0.29      0.00     96.35
04:55:01 PM     all      1.31      0.00      0.11      0.40      0.00     98.18
05:00:01 PM     all      1.52      0.00      0.11      0.22      0.00     98.15
05:05:01 PM     all      1.91      0.00      0.15      1.81      0.00     96.14
05:10:01 PM     all      1.11      0.00      0.10      0.22      0.00     98.57
05:15:01 PM     all      0.76      0.00      0.09      0.01      0.00     99.14
05:20:01 PM     all      1.70      0.00      0.28      0.41      0.00     97.61
05:25:01 PM     all      0.77      0.00      0.09      0.09      0.00     99.05
Average:        all     11.49      0.00      0.64      2.15      0.00     85.72


sar -q -s 12:00:00 -e 18:00:00 -f /var/log/sa/sa10

12:00:01 PM   runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15
12:05:01 PM         0       430      0.09      0.12      0.12
12:10:01 PM         0       423      0.06      0.09      0.09
12:15:01 PM         0       427      0.21      0.09      0.08
12:20:01 PM         0       423      0.21      0.15      0.10
12:25:01 PM         0       427      0.08      0.12      0.09
12:30:01 PM         2       428      0.15      0.16      0.11
12:35:01 PM         0       427      0.08      0.11      0.09
12:40:01 PM         0       423      0.08      0.08      0.08
12:45:01 PM         0       423      0.12      0.08      0.08
12:50:01 PM         0       423      0.02      0.06      0.08
12:55:01 PM         0       423      0.05      0.06      0.07
01:00:01 PM         0       423      0.19      0.09      0.08
01:05:01 PM         0       427      0.31      0.17      0.10
01:10:01 PM         0       427      0.22      0.19      0.12
01:15:01 PM         0       423      0.23      0.20      0.12
01:20:01 PM         1       423      0.12      0.19      0.13
01:25:02 PM         0       427      0.17      0.15      0.12
01:30:01 PM         0       429      0.16      0.14      0.11
01:35:01 PM         0       429      0.11      0.11      0.09
01:40:01 PM         0       423      0.08      0.07      0.08
01:45:01 PM         0       423      0.10      0.08      0.08
01:50:01 PM         2       423      0.27      0.15      0.10
01:55:01 PM         0       429      0.22      0.31      0.17
02:00:01 PM         0       429      0.38      0.25      0.17
02:05:01 PM         0       427      0.18      0.17      0.16
02:10:01 PM         0       427      0.14      0.15      0.15
02:15:01 PM         0       427      0.01      0.07      0.10
02:20:01 PM         1       423      0.10      0.09      0.09
02:25:01 PM         0       430      0.15      0.13      0.10
02:30:01 PM         3       428      0.01      0.05      0.07
02:35:01 PM         0       427      0.22      0.13      0.10
02:40:01 PM         1       430      0.20      0.17      0.11
02:45:01 PM         0       430      0.13      0.13      0.09
02:50:01 PM         0       430      0.29      0.22      0.13
02:55:01 PM         0       430      0.85      0.37      0.20
03:00:02 PM         0       430      0.12      0.23      0.18
03:05:01 PM         0       429      0.38      0.27      0.19
03:10:01 PM         0       429      0.23      0.24      0.19
03:15:01 PM         0       423      0.08      0.22      0.18
03:20:01 PM         0       423      0.10      0.15      0.16
03:25:01 PM         1       423      0.06      0.11      0.14
03:30:01 PM         0       439      1.01      0.46      0.26
03:35:01 PM         0       440      0.04      0.21      0.21
03:40:01 PM         0       440      0.15      0.15      0.17
03:45:01 PM         0       440      0.17      0.13      0.15
03:50:01 PM         1       440      0.28      0.21      0.17
03:55:01 PM         0       440      0.15      0.23      0.18
04:00:01 PM         0       438      0.42      0.29      0.20
04:05:01 PM         0       438      0.12      0.22      0.18
04:10:01 PM         0       438      0.15      0.20      0.18
04:15:01 PM         0       438      0.29      0.22      0.19
04:20:01 PM         1       436      0.17      0.24      0.19
04:25:01 PM         0       434      0.24      0.30      0.22
04:30:01 PM         1       441      0.32      0.33      0.26
04:35:01 PM         3       440      0.28      0.26      0.24
04:40:01 PM         0       440      0.21      0.24      0.24
04:45:02 PM         0       438      0.14      0.19      0.21
04:50:01 PM         0       438      0.47      0.28      0.23
04:55:01 PM         0       438      0.11      0.18      0.18
05:00:01 PM         0       438      0.12      0.14      0.16
05:05:01 PM         0       438      0.10      0.13      0.14
05:10:01 PM         0       438      0.15      0.12      0.13
05:15:01 PM         0       438      0.11      0.09      0.10
05:20:01 PM         0       434      0.18      0.15      0.11
05:25:01 PM         0       440      0.19      0.17      0.11
05:30:01 PM         1       440      0.35      0.18      0.11
05:35:01 PM         0       440      0.18      0.18      0.12
05:40:01 PM         0       440      0.12      0.11      0.09
05:45:01 PM         0       434      0.04      0.06      0.07
05:50:01 PM         0       434      0.04      0.10      0.08
05:55:01 PM         0       434      0.05      0.08      0.08
Average:            0       431      0.19      0.17      0.14
```